# Have the text on a clicked menu item

Tags: c#, wpf, menu

I have a menu with a menuItem in it. This menuItem has items that are dynamically added to my code.
This is what it looks like:

[image]

I added a click event to my MenuItem.
Here is the code of the event:

```
private void MenuItem_facturesRécentes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show((sender as System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem).Header.ToString());
}
```

This code, for me, is supposed to drown me the text of the item click while when I press on one of my two items, the dialog box displays: "Facture récente" which is the name of the parent menu item.

With you a solution to retrieve the text of the item click?

Thank you.

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794">
    <MenuItem x:Name="MenuItem_facturesRécentes" Header="Factures récentes" Height="23" Click="MenuItem_facturesRécentes_Click">
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: No, it's WPF, there is no parameter for .Text.

Comment: Try `((MenuItem)e.OriginalSource).Header;`

Comment: please mark my answer if it helped you to solve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try below Code

```
((MenuItem)e.OriginalSource).Header;
```

As Per docs:

> The original reporting source, before any possible Source adjustment made by class handling, which may have been done to flatten composited element trees.

So you'll get your menu from e.original source